# How to make a list component to list my contentful posts

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful

I'm trying to make a list component that lists off my project Case Studies coming from my Contentful account. I'm trying to use Gatsby's Static Query component.

I tried to bring the data in and map it to the list item component that basically takes the Title and URL as props into a Link component like as follows:

```
<li><Link to={this.props.url} >{this.props.title}</Link></li>
```

This is what I have: (ignore the misspelling in caseStudyTitile...)

```
import React from 'react'
import CaseItem from './caseItem/caseItem';

import { StaticQuery } from 'gatsby';

const Cases = () => (
    <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
        query CaseStudyQuery {
            allContentfulCaseStudy {
                edges {
                    node {
                        caseStudyTitile
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        `}
        render={data => (
            <div className="Cases">
                <h3>Case Studies</h3>
                <ul>
                    {data.allContentfulCaseStudy.edges.map(node => (
                        <CaseItem 
                            title={node.caseStudyTitile} 
                            url={node.slug}/>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )}
    />

)

export default Cases
```

I expect to get a list of clickable links to my Case Studies. Instead I'm getting a list of empty List Items with empty Links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since edges is shaped like this `[{ node: {...} }, { node: {...} }, ...]`
You'd need to unwrap node:

```
- data.allContentfulCaseStudy.edges.map(node => (
+ data.allContentfulCaseStudy.edges.map(({ node }) => (
```

If you're using gatsby 2.2.0 and above, you can use this shortcut query:

```
  query CaseStudyQuery {
    allContentfulCaseStudy {
      nodes {  // <--- short for `edges { node { ... } }`
        caseStudyTitile
        slug
      }
    }
  }
```

and access it much easier like `data.allContentfulCaseStudy.nodes.map(node => ...)`